# Send response to Dialogflow webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm trying to implement Dialogflow bot. I've set all intents, the response defined for the intent and webhook receiver controller. It works well but based on [Fulfillment docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#webhook_response) after Dialogflow request to my webhook service I need to send response to Dialogflow. How to do that?

Here is my webhook service:

```
class Api::V1::WebhooksController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods

  http_basic_authenticate_with name: Rails.application.credentials.webhook_auth_name, password: Rails.application.credentials.webhook_auth_password

  def create
    action_name = params[:webhook][:queryResult][:intent][:displayName]

    case action_name
    when 'get-calendar'
      render json: 'Show calendar', status: :ok
    when 'get-room'
      render json: 'Show available rooms', status: :ok
    end
  end
end
```

Which gives me that message inside `Raw interaction log` :

```
{
  "queryText": "Calendar",
  "parameters": {},
  "fulfillmentText": "<happy>This is your calendar</happy>",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "<happy>This is your calendar</happy>"
        ]
      },
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "intent": {
    "id": "1234",
    "displayName": "get-calendar",
    "priority": 500000,
    "webhookState": "WEBHOOK_STATE_ENABLED",
    "messages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "<happy>This is your calendar</happy>"
          ]
        },
        "lang": "en"
      }
    ]
  },
  "intentDetectionConfidence": 1234,
  "diagnosticInfo": {
    "webhook_latency_ms": 1234
  },
  "languageCode": "en",
  "slotfillingMetadata": {
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true
  },
  "id": "1234",
  "sessionId": "1234",
  "timestamp": "2020-09-25T14:38:31.92Z",
  "source": "agent",
  "webhookStatus": {
    "webhookEnabledForAgent": true,
    "webhookStatus": {
      "code": 3,
      "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Expect message object but got: \"Show\"."
    }
  },
  "agentEnvironmentId": {
    "agentId": "1324",
    "cloudProjectId": "test-project"
  }
}
```

I don't think this part is what I expected:

```
  "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Expect message object but got: \"Show\"."
```

Answer (score 0):

DialogFlow calls your WebHook when processing an Intent, you need to ensure your code send back a JSON object which DialogFlow understands and can process. It looks like you are sending back just a text message (Show Calendar), or at least a JSON starting with `Show..'

You are using DialogFlow API v1 (this is deprecated, better move to V2) so your JSON [should look like this](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-json/blob/master/responses/v1/response.json). Normally there are SDK (Java, NodeJS, I guess Ruby too?) which provides the model and objects to work with, so you don't need to create the JSON manually but just use the API.